# Request.ServerVariables("..") returns undefined when assigned to a variable yet its value can be displayed via Response.Write("..")

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

I am trying to retrieve the user's IP address and assign it to a variable:

```
var ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") || 
                Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") || 
                Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"); 

Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") + "<br />\n\n");    // produces "localhost"
Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") + "<br />\n\n");  // produces "::1"
Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") + "<br />\n\n"); // produces "undefined"
Response.Write("ipAddress = " + typeof ipAddress + " " + ipAddress + "<br />\n\n");     // produces "ipAddress = object undefined"
```

I am using JScript for Classic ASP.  I am unsure as to what to do at this point.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You are assigning `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")` first which is set to `undefined` as proved when you `Response.Write()` it out singularly later in the script. If it’s undefined, what do you expect, not sure the `||` logic is right in this instance.

Comment: I am simply trying to assign your IP address to a variable, ipAddress, which is housed in one or more objects in Request.ServerVariables.  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR may have it, but if not, REMOTE_ADDR or HTTP_HOST may have it, but I want to be sure that I obtain the assigned value in one of them to ipAddress

Answer (score 3):

Things work in ASP with JScript a little bit different than ASP with VBScript.

Since everything is an object in JavaScript, with `var ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")` you get an object reference instead of a string value because like most of other `Request` collections, the `ServerVariables` is a collection of `IStringList` objects

So, to make that short-circuit evaluation work as you expect, you need to play with the values, not the object references.

You can use the `Item` method that returns the string value of `IStringList` object if there's a value (the key exists), otherwise it returns an `Empty` value that evaluated as `undefined` in JScript.

```js
var ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR").Item || 
                Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR").Item || 
                Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST").Item;
```

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: @Lankymart Thank you. I'd use JScript more if things like this were easy as well as in VBScript. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but I found a rather unique solution to my problem a while back, but I will consider this for the future.  JScript is a PITA

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem with obtaining the IP address, and the truthyness/falsyness of JScript is a complete and utter nightmare.

```
if (!String.prototype.isNullOrEmpty) {
        String.isNullOrEmpty = function(value) {
            return (typeof value === 'undefined' || value == null || value.length == undefined || value.length == 0);
        };
}

var ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") || 
                Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") || 
                Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"); 

function getIPAddress() {
        try {
            if (String.isNullOrEmpty(ipAddress)) {
                ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
            }
            
            if (String.isNullOrEmpty(ipAddress)) {
                ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR");
            }
            
            if (String.isNullOrEmpty(ipAddress)) {
                ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST");
            }
        } catch (e) {
            Response.Write("From getIPAddress(): " + e.message);
            hasErrors = true;
        } finally {
            return ipAddress;
        }
}


    ipAddress = getIPAddress();
    Response.Write("ipAddress = " + typeof ipAddress + " " + ipAddress + "<br />\n\n");     // produces "object localhost"
```